# How to declare a public variable variable in a class

Tags: php, oop, class, variables, declaration

Hey I have a class like this

```
class derp{

public $$ini;

public static function regIni($ini){

derp::$$ini = 'test';

}

}
```

And then in another file I have

```
core::regIni('register');
```

And then somewhere else I use

```
core::$register;
```

This produces an error

```
public $$ini
```

is not valid code but if I leave it without I can not set

```
core::$$ini
```

How do I fix this?

Please note that $$ini is a variable variable meaning the value of $ini is actuely the variable name so $ini = 'registry' then $$ini actualy means $registry.

Comment: It's not doable. Static properties can only be defined at the parsing stage. Neither `ReflectionProperty` or `ReflectionClass::setStaticPropertyValue`, nor `runkit_*` functions are currently capable (intended) to create static class properties. Sorry.

Comment: @mario Thanks for the clear comment, I would put this as the accepted answer if I could but its commen. I geuss i'll just have to drop the static class en make a normal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is not an overly helpful answer, as I can just conclude that it's currently not possible.

- You cannot define a `new ReflectionProperty("derp", "static_prop")` for example and attach it. It's really for introspection only.
- `$c = new ReflectionClass("derp");` and `$derp->setStaticPropertyValue("p", 123);` is not working either. The properties need to be predefined still.
- And lastly, neither can the [`runkit_*` functions](http://php.net/runkit) help with this task. They are intended for changing methods mainly.
- Same for [classkit](https://www.php.net/classkit).

I'm not aware of other such PECL extensions, but that wouldn't be useful as general solution anyway. So for current PHP versions you cannot add static class properties after the parsing stage.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use access methods for setting and getting class data?

```
class derp {

    protected static $_data = array(); 

    public static function regIni($ini, $value) {
         derp::$_data[$ini] = $value;   
    }

    public static function getIni($ini, $default = NULL) {
        return isset(derp::$_data[$ini]) ? derp::$_data[$ini] : $default;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to it, I ended up trying magic methods first, only to realize they don't go well with static.

Comment: So now this would derp:getIni('register') it would now if register would be a class now I would have to go $class = derp::getIni('register') and then $class->function();? this is not really an an anwser to my question just a diffrent solution it does I still can't dynamicly create variables for the class.

Comment: Now you can use `derp::setIni('register', 'some value');` and `$register = derp::getIni('register');`.

Comment: That seems like a lot more then necasery would't it me be much easier to have core::register->function instead of having having to copy register in a diffrent variable. This method you posted would be fine for variables and stuff but I don't want do create new variables for classes I have in my main class

Comment: @biakaveron This is a really important part of my code and should be done propaly. There writing a reg and get functions should be avoided as it will just be more work later on.

Comment: Php doesnt copy object variables, just creates a link to it. But I still have no thoughts about what do you want :)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at magic methods __set and __get

Comment: You are right, seems like they don´t work with static, sorry.

Comment: As of PHP 5.3.0, a warning is issued if one of the magic overloading methods is declared static.

Comment: That's OK, I only knew this because that was my first idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mario said:

> It's not doable. Static properties can
>   only be defined at the parsing stage.
>   Neither ReflectionProperty or
>   ReflectionClass::setStaticPropertyValue,
>   nor runkit_* functions are currently
>   capable (intended) to create static
>   class properties. Sorry

Geuss i'l settle for a work around then.
Made an array $ini and loaded the values into there derp:$ini['base']['key']

Thanks for the help,

Robin